# Advice on MySQL JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am struggling to get me head round the MySQL Join function.

Here is two tables I have:

User table:

```
admin_id     username
  *1          peter93
   2       stackoverflowrocks
   3          user3*
```

Admin details table:

```
   admin_username     description        image
       pedro93          [text]        [image_url]
 stackoverflowrocks     [text]        [image_url]
        user3           [text]        [image_url]
```

I know usualy to link two databases together you would use ID numbers, but in this case I want to join the two tables where admin_username = username.

Can anyone help me please? It is for a PHP script if that helps.

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So that's fine. You can join on anything you like.

```
select * 
from user
    inner join admin
    on user.username=admin.admin_username
```

Comment: Note that joining using non indexed columns will be incur a performance hit. For large tables, it could be 100's of times slower.

Comment: Hi there,  I am using your method, it was workin great but I tried to add a WHERE LIKE clause and now I get no results?

Comment: To help here is my full query (I know its a little different from the example in the question)

Comment: SELECT * FROM ticket_agents t INNER JOIN user u ON (t.admin_id = u.user_id) WHERE u.username LIKE 'peter%'

Comment: Nothing immediately wrong with the query. In the admin tables, the admin_username is pedro, not peter. (This is why people join on IDs, btw)

Comment: But if you were to see the program I am working on it would make sense to you lol! Anyway the no results came down to a PHP problem. All sorted now.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

joining by a string column is the same as joining by Id

```
select * from admin_table
inner join admin_details on admin_table.username = admin_details.admin_username
```

But make sure you have and index for the username columns, or else your queries will go slow when you have lots of records

Comment: I read that online just after posting the question, I am trying it now!

Comment: @podiluska agreed. i was in a hurry :)

Answer (score 1):

You can join on pretty much any field but you may wish to keep in mind datatype mismatching, indexing etc

All users

```
SELECT u.*, a.*
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN admin AS a 
       ON u.username = a.username
```

All users that are admin

```
SELECT u.*, a.*
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN admin AS a 
       ON u.username = a.username
```

All admin

```
SELECT u.*, a.*
FROM users AS u
RIGHT JOIN admin AS a 
       ON u.username = a.username
```